# SharePoint 2010 OOTB filtering and sorting is not working in XsltListViewWebPart in Arabic

Tags: sorting, sharepoint-2010, filtering

I am working on a multilingual site in English and Arabic. I have some pages with XsltListViewWebPart to view custom lists with no more than 12 fields to display. These are connecting webparts and provides filter values to another XsltListViewWebPart on same page.

When I open this page in Arabic its OOTB filtering and sorting does not work and also it does not show Display form when i click on Title of any of the list items.

When I click on any of the column headers it shows the filtering and sorting menu with all option and filtering values but after click nothing happens.

However if there is any lookup field in same webpart and when i click on that it shows display form of that particulat lookup item.

This happenss only if I open these pages in Arabic.. in English everything works fine.

Nothing is customized but conditional formating on one column and added connection between webparts.